# Find $\displaystyle \lim \limits_{x\rightarrow0} \sum \limits_{k=1}^{2013}\frac{\{x/\tan x+2k\}}{2013}$ where {$x$} denotes fractional part of $x$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$\displaystyle \lim \limits_{x\rightarrow0} \sum \limits_{k=1}^{2013}\frac{\{x/\tan x+2k\}}{2013}$

RHL: Let $x=a+h, h>0$ and $a=0$

$\displaystyle \lim \limits_{h\rightarrow0} \sum \limits_{k=1}^{2013}\frac{\{h/\tan h+2k\}}{2013}=\lim \limits_{h\rightarrow0} \sum \limits_{k=1}^{2013}\frac{\{1+2k\}}{2013}$ which will always be zero since $k$ is an integer.

LHL: Let $x=a-h, h>0$ and $a=0$

$\displaystyle \lim \limits_{h\rightarrow0} \sum \limits_{k=1}^{2013}\frac{\{-h/\tan (-h)+2k\}}{2013}=\lim \limits_{h\rightarrow0} \sum \limits_{k=1}^{2013}\frac{\{-h/-\tan (h)+2k\}}{2013}=\lim \limits_{h\rightarrow0} \sum \limits_{k=1}^{2013}\frac{\{1+2k\}}{2013}$ which will always be zero since $k$ is an integer.

So the limit should be zero, but my answer is wrong. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I don't think writing $x=a+h\text{ }(a=0)$ will be helpful, since then $h\to 0$ as $x\to 0$, which brings us back to our original limit.

Comment: For $x \in (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}) \setminus \{0\}$, $\frac{x}{\tan x} \in (0,1) \implies \{ \frac{x}{\tan x} + 2k \} = \frac{x}{\tan x}$

Comment: @achillehui How can we prove $x/tanx \in (0,1)$?

Comment: Consider $f(x) = \tan x - x$ on $x \in [0, \pi/2)$ and do some calculus.

Comment: By MVT, for any $x \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$,  there is a  $y \in (0,x)$ such that $\frac{\tan x}{x} = \left(\tan x)'\right|_y = 1+(\tan y)^2 > 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\displaystyle \lim \limits_{x\rightarrow0} \sum \limits_{k=1}^{2013}\frac{\{x/\tan x+2k\}}{2013}=\displaystyle \lim \limits_{x\rightarrow0} \sum \limits_{k=1}^{2013}\frac{x/\tan x+2k}{2013}-\displaystyle \lim \limits_{x\rightarrow0} \sum \limits_{k=1}^{2013}\frac{[x/\tan x+2k]}{2013}$$

$$S_1=\lim \limits_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x}{\tan x}+2014$$

$$S_2=\displaystyle\sum \limits_{k=1}^{2013}\frac{2k}{2013}=2014\;\;\;(*)$$

The difference yields the result.

---

where

**1)**$[.]$ denotes the GIF function

**2)** $(*)$ follows since $2k$ is a, positive integer and $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x}{\tan x}=1^-$

Comment: Note: this is an alternative approach to the question since the method OP used has been proven wrong already in the comments. Also, this is the GIF approach of what @achille hui used(very similar)